# connecting to Lotus notes through C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am trying to connect to Lotus notes through C#. For this i am using below code

NotesSession ns = new Domino.NotesSession(); 
ns.Initialize();

i am getting "The system cannot find the file specified." error while initializing session, if i have not opened lotus notes client on my machine.

How ever if Lotus notes client is open, i am not getting this error.

Is it mandatory to have lotus notes client open for connecting to lotus notes with out this error. Am i missing some thing. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass a pathname to the notes.ini file. Try that. 
Make sure that a valid ID file name is specified in the notes.ini variable KeyFileName . 
E. g. 
KeyFileName=yournotesid.id
The ID file is supposed to be in the notes data directory. The path to the id file specified in the notes.ini is relative to the data directory.